# System Slow - Event Registration with Payment

Tags: civievent, payment-processor

On events which require payment, the system takes up to 2 minutes to generate the second page of the registration process, which is the page titled "Confirm Your Registration Information".

What is the problem, and what can I do to bring the performance up to acceptable levels?

The site runs quickly on every other page, including other CiviCRM tasks. It is only this process which is slow.

Comment: whats your payment processor? Can you do a test run and use the dummy payment processor and see if it is still slow

Comment: Do other CiviCRM functions run more quickly, or is it potentially a server resources issue? What kind of a server are you running on?

Comment: Yes, everything else seems to run quickly. The site runs smooth across the board. I have all caching disabled, but it's still loading quickly, except for this page.

Comment: Payment processor is Authorize.net

Answer (score 5):

If I'm looking at the right site, it looks like the second page of your event registration has a consistent 60 second delay added on top of the usual page generation times, and that the delay is introduced before the user is asked for payment.

Unless your payment processor requires communication before the transaction, this suggests that the issue is within CiviCRM or your hosting environment.

**An additional 60 or 120 second delay is often a timeout**, for example when a webserver attempts to get reverse DNS during the request and fails. However there's no way to be sure without looking under the hood, so I'll provide general advice on how to proceed also :)

- Use tools like http://www.webpagetest.org or http://fpt.pingdom.com to ensure your site performs well generally - enter the URL of your registration pages and make sure *the entire page* is delivered to the visitor within a few seconds.
- Ensure your hosting environment is capable of delivering your content in a reasonable timeframe.
- Disable configurations which add to request time, eg reverse DNS lookups.

I suspect this issue is not related to your payment processor at all.

Comment: Pingdom and webpagetest.org show the site is good overall. Hosting environment is a managed cloud server from Rochen, and is doing well. We have a dedicated MySQL db server as well, which is running good also. I haven't looked into reverse DNS lookups.

Comment: If you have a separate DB server, you may see DNS issues between webserver and DB server also. Make sure both servers recognise all hostnames used in communication (caching DNS or /etc/hosts entries). Note that rDNS is only one possible cause of this behaviour - but I've seen it happen plenty, and it's frequently a source of confusion because it's not obvious.

Comment: I think your next step is to contact your developers and have them investigate the issue. If it's reproducible, it should be straightforward for a developer with access to the system to identify and eliminate.